# Can Startup Manager be used to boot Linux operating systems?

Tags: unix, startup

This is a pretty simple question and I'm thinking the answer is no, but can Mac's Startup Manager be used to boot Linux based operating systems?  I'll probably end up installing a tool like rEFInd later on but I want to double check first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you don't have FileVault and if you plan to install it on a partition (which you probably do). You can just hold `alt`/`option` and it should show `Macintosh HD`, `Recovery HD`, and `Linux` (or whatever you named it). You can cycle through with arrows and hit `enter` to confirm. If that doesn't work, you might just install rEFInd :(

Comment: Okay. I also read up on it and it looks like it'll work but because I want the default OS to be Linux I'll probably need to use rEFInd.

Comment: If you want the default OS to be linux, you can just go to apple's system preferences, and set the default startup disk. Then you boot to linux, unless you hold alt to switch to OS X

Comment: Oh cool, that works.  I suppose I'm kind of trying to avoid to install rEFInd, mostly because it's a rather ugly interface.  Startup Manager seems quieter and more what I'm looking for in this situation.  Thanks for the tip.